# Calculate the sum based on the ranking of another matrix

Tags: matlab

I have two relatively large metrices (the two charts below are examples). The first matrix is the ranking of five stocks (in five columns but one of columns has missing values) in five days. The second matrix is the market cap of these five stocks in five days. What I hope to do is, for each day, select stocks whose sum of market caps is no more than the column six, based on the descending order of rows in the first matrix. For example, in day 1, choose stock 3 first, followed by stock 2. The next is stock 5, but the total market cap will be larger than the column 6, so only two stocks are selected. Next, a new matrix is created, with selected stocks being 1 and non-selected stocks being 0. Thanks! Here is the ranking matrix

```
Days    Stock 1 Stock 2 Stock 3 Stock 4 Stock 5
Day 1         1       3       4     #N/A      2
Day 2         3       4       2        1    #N/A
Day 3         4       3      #N/A      1      1
Day 4        #N/A     1       2        3      4
Day 5        #N/A     3       2        1      4
```

Here is the market cap matrix:

```
Days    Stock 1 Stock 2 Stock 3 Stock 4 Stock 5 Column 6
Day 1         20      30      30      #N/A    55    67.50
Day 2         25      35      35      43     #N/A   69.00
Day 3         89      88     #N/A     34     100    155.50
Day 4         #N/A    33      82      99      11    112.50
Day 5         #N/A    33      22      44      33    66.00
```

Comment: I recommend you try to write code for this and post your attempt. That would help the community identify and solve the specific part you're having trouble with.

Comment: I have to admit that I'm a matlab newbie. This above question completely overwhelmed me and that I have little idea about it...

Comment: In that case it is time to start with something easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have enough time to provide a vectorized solution, which is what you should always attempt to obtain in Matlab... but this should work:

```
D = 5;

R = [
    1   3  4   NaN 2;
    3   4  2   1   NaN;
    4   3  NaN 1   1;
    NaN 1  2   3   4;
    NaN 3  2   1   4
];

M = [
    20  30  30  NaN 55    67.50;
    25  35  35  43  NaN   69.00;
    89  88  NaN 34  100  155.50;
    NaN 33  82  99  11   112.50;
    NaN 33  22  44  33    66.00
];

sel = cell(D,1);

for i = 1:D
    M_curr = M(i,:);

    R_curr = R(i,:);
    R_nan = isnan(R_curr);
    R_curr(R_nan) = -Inf;

    [~,R_idx] = sort(R_curr,'descend');
    R_idx_end = 5 - sum(R_nan);

    if (R_idx_end == 0)
        sel{i} = [];
        continue;
    end

    R_idx = R_idx(1:R_idx_end);

    M_cs = cumsum(M_curr(R_idx));
    M_cs_lim = find(M_cs <= M_curr(6));

    sel{i} = [R_idx(M_cs_lim) repmat([0],5-numel(M_cs_lim),1).'];
end
```

Actually, the last part (the structure of the result), is really unclear so I went for a simple cell result.